# How to run dask in multiple machines?

Tags: dask

I found Dask recently. I have very basic questions about Dask Dataframe and other data structures.

1. Is Dask Dataframe immutable data type?
2. Is Dask array and Dataframe are lazy data structure?

I dont know whether to use dask or spark or pandas for my situation. I have 200 GB of data to compute. It took 9 hours to compute operations using plain python program. But it can be processed parallelly in lesser time by utilizing 16 core processor. If I split the dataframe in pandas I need to worry about commutative and associative property of my calculations. On the other hand I can use standalone spark cluster to just split up the data and run parallelly.

Do I need to setup any clusters in Dask as like as Spark?
How to run Dask dataframes in my own compute nodes?
Does Dask need master-slave setup?

I am a fan of pandas, so I am looking for solutions similar to pandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appear to be a few questions here

#### Q: Are Dask.dataframes immutable?

Not strictly.  They support column assignment.  Generally though you're correct that most of the mutation operations of Pandas are not supported

#### Q: Are Dask.dataframe and Dask.array lazy?

Yes

#### Q: Do I need to set up a cluster?

No, you can choose to run Dask on a cluster or on a single machine.

#### Q: If I want to use a cluster how do I do it?

See documentation for [Dask.distributed](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the [setup docs](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html) in particular

#### Q: Should I use Dask, Spark, or Pandas?

This question is overly broad and depends on the situation

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Is there a documentation how to actually setup a `Cluster`? Like for the `LocalCluster` as in the docs? Coming from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902582/dask-setup-a-cluster-where-multiple-machines-can-connect-to