# Dask: Setup a Cluster where multiple machines can connect to

Tags: dask-distributed

[From the docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/adaptive.html?highlight=distributed.deploy#distributed.deploy.Cluster), there is a class called `Cluster`, but other than for the `LocalCluster`, I can not find any docs about **how to setup a Cluster which accepts workers from different machines** (as this is described for `LocalCluster`[here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html).

Are there some recommendations out there?

Related question: [1 (only reference on the docs as above)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39439548/940592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [SSHCluster](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/ssh.html)
It is based on `asyncssh`and can have multiple workers per machine in the cluster. Make sure to have pre requirements installed.